# Matrix and its characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial, cayley-hamilton

> Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$.
> Prove that the characteristic polynomial of A can be written as $p(\lambda) = \lambda^2 − trace(A)\lambda + det(A)$ and show that $A$ satisfies its own characteristic equation $p(A) = 0_{2 \times 2}$.

I had a hard time following the lecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINTS**

Let $A$ be a square matrix. The *characteristic polynomial* of $A$ is defined as
$$
p(\lambda) = \det(A- \lambda I), \quad \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
It is useful, among other things, in determining eigenvalues, since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if it is a root of $p$.

For the specific case of a $2 \times 2$ matrix, let
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$$
then
$$
p(\lambda)
 = \det(A- \lambda I)
 = \begin{vmatrix} a - \lambda & b \\ c & d - \lambda \end{vmatrix}
$$

Now, you can

- compute $\det A$ and $\mathrm{tr}\ A$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$
- compute the actual expression for $p(\lambda)$
- observe that $p(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - \mathrm{tr}(A) + \det(A)$ as requested
- plug in $A$ into $p$ and compute, observing that $p(A)$ is the zero matrix.

The final observation is true not just for a $2 \times 2$ matrix, but for any square matrix, and is called the [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

Comment: Quite a bit more than a hint.  It is better for you, instead of answering immediately, to coach the asker to improve their question.  You don't even have a clue as to what, exactly, the OP doesn't understand in the lecture.  Taking stabs in the dark do not good answers make.

Comment: @amWhy I see you like Yoda, me too :) The OP complained about not being able to follow lecture, so I was thinking they missed the whole concept. So I tried to outline it for them, without giving away any work to be done. In such cases, unfortunately, it is very likely to encounter the OP who would not be able to verbalize what exactly it is they don't understand. (Seemed like they did not get the concept entirely.) I thought this answer would be a nice invitation to do some work, seems like it worked, I guess... That said, would you still prefer me to ask next time?

Comment: @amWhy one major bonus of your approach - the OP learns to ask questions... I've seen a bunch, unfortunately, where the questions would just get closed and OP would not get anything out of the experience. This way, the concept is home, but they still have to do all the work (hence a hint - let me know what else would you prefer I call it, since an answer in my mind is something completely done)

Comment: That makes good sense.  I understand.  In some cases, I prefer potential answers to try to help the OP clarify, but I trust your judgment here.  Thanks for the reply!  (minor edit on my part, to enable the reversal of my vote on it!)

Comment: @amWhy you should know I really appreciate you taking time to teach me how to make this place better. I learned *a lot* from you in my time on Math.SE and really appreciate your time and effort. Thank you.